# Cloudera does not generate missing kerberos credentials for Flume

Tags: kerberos, cloudera, flume, flume-ng, cloudera-manager

I have installed Flume after installing main services and enabling Kerberos. And not when I run `Generate Missing Credentials` t says `No roles required Kerberos credentials to be generated.`, which is wrong since Flume needs a principal `flume` to be created.

Is there a way to hint Cloudera to generate credentials for Flume?

Comment: *(a)* `flume` is a Linux user name, not a Kerberos principal; *(b)* the way I see it, Flume is a **client** of kerberized services (such as HDFS or Kafka), so it can use any client principal to authenticate _(i.e. your own Active Directory account, or an AD service account)_ -- no need for a Kerberos SPN. It's HDFS or Kafka, i.e. the kerberized services, that need a Service Principal for each node, like `hdfs/myhost1.mydomain@MY.KRB.REALM`.

Comment: I have added pricipal manually for Flume and it worked.